# How to match time period with regex?

Tags: python, regex

Currently I use the following regex to find time periods:

```
.*(30 minutes|1 hour|1 hour 30 minutes|2 hours|2 hours 30 minutes|3 hours|3 hours 30 minutes|4 hours)
```

How can I simplify it and support more time periods here (for ex., up to 24 hours)?

Comment: Can we state that in your case there would be only `<num> hours <num> minutes` sequences, without say `seconds, milliseconds` ?

Comment: If you don't whant to check that it is correct but only select `(?:\d+ (?:minute|hour)s? ?){1,2}` - https://regex101.com/r/Hb3FEk/1

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can factorize `30 minutes` like this:

```
(30 minutes|1 hour(?: 30 minutes)?|(?:[2-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4]) hours(?: 30 minutes)?)
```

Where:

- `(?: 30 minutes)?` means option 30 minutes
- `(?:[2-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])` is a range from 2 up to 24 hours